# angular js radio buttons display and print

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, radio-button

I'm trying to modify the following code so the input element idEcho prints the value of the radio button being clicked, and instead of the current label display, i want to show W1, W2, W3 and W4 correspondingly.
and i want the values returned by the clicked radio buttons to be N1, N2, N3 and N4.

```html
<body>
<label ng‐repeat="w in radioDetails">
  {{w.what}}:
  <input type="radio" ng‐model="$parent.mSelection" value={{w.what}}><br>
</label>
<input id="idEcho" type="text">

<script>
  myModule=angular.module("appEX",[]);
  myModule.controller("ctrl", function($scope){   
    $scope.mSelection="a1";
    $scope.radioDetails=[
      {what:"a1",yes:"W1",no:"N1"},
      {what:"a2",yes:"W2",no:"N2"},
      {what:"a3",yes:"W3",no:"N3"},
      {what:"a4",yes:"W4",no:"N4"}
    ];
  });
</script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

all that assuming proper angular js setup
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<label ng‐repeat="w in radioDetails">
  {{w.yes}}:
  <input type="radio" ng‐model="$parent.mSelection" value={{w.no}}><br>
</label>
<input id="idEcho" type="text" ng‐model="$parent.mSelection">
```